What's wrong with these CSS Media queries? - or with me. It has to be one of the two of us at fault
So, as far as I ca tell, my code ~should~ work. but it doesn't. Chrome's developer tools show me that my browser is recognising the  >501px condition and applying the CSS, but not the smaller viewport condition. I thought maybe it was a wierd browser cache thing, but no... it happens to a simplified page made to demo the problem, and on Safari too.
So, after 2 days of web building, and having had so many more complex wins along the way, I'm stumped in this apparently simple-not-simple thing.
Could someone please put me out of my misery and tell me why this doesn't unfloat the div when the Browser gets thin?
an image showing the problem in using Chrome
<html>
<head>
<style>

#aboutblock { 
    width:90%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    text-align:justify;
    }


@media all and (min-width: 501px) { 
#aboutblock img {
    float:left; 
    width:400px; 
    margin:1%;
    margin: 0% 3% 2% 0%;
    }

}


@media all and (max-width: 500px) { 
#aboutblock img {
    float:none;
    width:277px; 
    margin:1%;
    margin: 0% 3% 2% 0%;
        
     } 
        
}
    
</style>
</head> 
        
    </body>
        <div class="blockcontainer">
            <div id="aboutblock">
                
                <img src="https://images.rawpixel.com/image_800/czNmcy1wcml2YXRlL3Jhd3BpeGVsX2ltYWdlcy93ZWJzaXRlX2NvbnRlbnQvbHIvZnJvd2xfbmlnaHRfb3dsX2FuaW1hbC1pbWFnZS1reWJjeWVqaS5qcGc.jpg" />
            
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sapien odio, sollicitudin a dolor at, sodales etc etc etc...</p>
            
                <p>Suspendisse potenti. Donec molestie aliquam lacus at laoreet. Donec justo risus, euismod quis augue a, etc etc etc...</p>
            
                <p>Sed efficitur rhoncus tristique. Sed vulputate, velit quis auctor convallis, erat lacus tincidunt sem, etc etc etc... </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>

As to the 'how' and 'why' and 'what have I done?'... I was building a website, got overtired, and now I can't even find a way into solving this seemingly small thing, which is surely my cue to get some sleep finally. ... but also, I'm now far too flustered with it!
I made a small, cleaned up version of the relevant part of the website I was building to make sure the problem wasn't with some conflict or such. I was not.
Test case is here. https://generous-tiger.static.domains/testpage
Honestly, I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious here, just in the hope that someone can put me out of my misery with it!

The test page works as expected for me.

Interesting! Thanks for taking a look at least.
When I look with Chrome and Safari on this end, it's definitely not unfloating the image here. I'll ee if I can edit to add an image to the post.

It works also for me, in Chrome 123.0.6312.86 and Firefox 124.0.1.
Did you try to clear browser cache?

Ah, you're using the mobile device view. The page is missing the viewport meta tag so media queries don't work as you expect.

Well, I'll be ... something or other!
I learned a valuable lesson today, and I will never forget the viewport meta tag again. I hope!
I added the tab in, and as if by magic, it turns out that I couldn't find a problem with the actual simple piece of code because there wasn't one.
Thank you, everybody, - and  Guy Incognito especially. I can finally sleep now.

As suggested in comments, it works as expected after adding viewport meta tag, including mobile device view:


<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>

#aboutblock { 
    width:90%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    text-align:justify;
    }


@media all and (min-width: 501px) { 
#aboutblock img {
    float:left; 
    width:400px; 
    margin:1%;
    margin: 0% 3% 2% 0%;
    }

}


@media all and (max-width: 500px) { 
#aboutblock img {
    float:none;
    width:277px; 
    margin:1%;
    margin: 0% 3% 2% 0%;
        
     } 
        
}
    
</style>
</head> 
        
    </body>
        <div class="blockcontainer">
            <div id="aboutblock">
                
                <img src="https://images.rawpixel.com/image_800/czNmcy1wcml2YXRlL3Jhd3BpeGVsX2ltYWdlcy93ZWJzaXRlX2NvbnRlbnQvbHIvZnJvd2xfbmlnaHRfb3dsX2FuaW1hbC1pbWFnZS1reWJjeWVqaS5qcGc.jpg" />
            
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sapien odio, sollicitudin a dolor at, sodales etc etc etc...</p>
            
                <p>Suspendisse potenti. Donec molestie aliquam lacus at laoreet. Donec justo risus, euismod quis augue a, etc etc etc...</p>
            
                <p>Sed efficitur rhoncus tristique. Sed vulputate, velit quis auctor convallis, erat lacus tincidunt sem, etc etc etc... </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>




This was absolutely it! Thank you, and all the other commenters, for helping me finally get some peaceful sleep tonight (in the land where it's definitely quite late at night right now.)

You're welcome, good night
